# Why is my drawer menu not responding when having a ConstraintLayout on the same XML?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-menu

I'm trying to add a drawer menu in two activities, one only has the drawer menu and the other one has the drawer menu and a ConstraintLayout beneath, the one without the ConstraintLayout works good, but the drawer menu of the other one doesn't respond, it doesn't scroll and if I try to select an option it just closes the drawer and does nothing.

Both XML are exactly the same except for the extra ConstraintLayout, if I remove the ConstraintLayout it works well but I need it for some controls.

this is the XML of the activity that doesn't work:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drwlayout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ac_Menu">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCompat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="395dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/mitoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drwamenu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        ></com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <ListView
            .... />

        <TextView
            ...... />

        <TextView
            ...... />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: `DrawerLayout` only supports two child views - the main view and the drawer view. Which of your views in your layout need to be in the main view vs in the drawer view?

Comment: ConstraintLayout would have the main controls and LinearLayoutCompat and NavigationView are for the drawer menu to work.

Comment: So both the `LinearLayoutCompat` and `ConstraintLayout` should be visible when the drawer is closed and the `NavigationView` should be visible when the drawer is open?

Comment: LinearLayoutCompat has a toolbar from which the drawer can be opened, NavigationView has the drawer menu, and ConstraintLayout the controls for the user. Following what you said about only supporting two child views, I tried to put the toolbar inside the ConstraintLayout to reduce the child to two but it didn't work